# Firebase recycler adapter not populating custom class

Tags: java, android

I created a custom class named Food that contained all the elements from my layout which I want to populate.
I set the setters and getter method in that class

```
     // Recycler View
private RecyclerView mFrooderList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


 //Setting Parameters for RecyclerView
    mFrooderList =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.frooder_list);
    mFrooderList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFrooderList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food");
```

Then I use Firebase Recycler adapter to populate my layout from Firebase Database

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>()
                .setQuery(mDatabase, Food.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
        // layout called R.layout.message for each item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_frooder_post, parent, false);

        return new FoodViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position, Food model) {

        mFrooderList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

};
```

But when I run the app it runs but I dont see my layout in the main Activity and in the run time I get this error

[image: error]

I don't know what I am doing wrong Please help

Comment: `No adapter attached`... You defined it. Didn't attach it

Comment: Move `setAdapter` *outside of* `onBindViewHolder` (and the adapter definition)

Comment: When I move it outside of OnBindViewHolder it gives me an error that unknown class

Comment: outside of the method, and the adapter definition. Outside the `};` below it

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` is where you take values from `Food model` and set them to the `FoodViewHolder holder`.

It is not where you set the adapter.

In other words, it should look like this

```
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position, Food model) {
           // TODO: Bind the ViewHolder
        }
    };  // end of adapter definition

    mFrooderList.setAdapter(adapter);

} // end onCreate
```

Comment: When I move it outside of OnBindViewHolder it gives me an error that unknown class and I am not sure what you mean by Bind the viewholder ?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace on `onCreate` in your image.

Comment: Or you've made `adapter` a field, and you can't set the adapter outside of a method

Comment: @cricket_007 I am setting the adapter but still data is not populating in my recycler view , using Firebase recycler adapter . You can check my question over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849772/in-firebase-recycler-adapter-onbindviewholder-and-oncreateviewholder-never-calle